# Tiled image with pixel coordinates projection by OpenLayers 7?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, tiles

I want to handle already-tiled static image with pixel coordinate by OpenLayers 7.

I coded like this:

```
const w = 14132;
const h = 16353;
const url = "https://t.tilemap.jp/maplat/tiles/naramachi_yasui_bunko/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg";
    
const extent = [0, 0, w, h];
const projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'xkcd-image',
  units: 'pixels',
  extent: extent,
});

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        projection: projection,
        url: url,
        tileSize: [256, 256],
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 6
      })
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: projection,
    zoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 6,
    constrainOnlyCenter: true
  }),
});

map.on('click', (e) => {
  const xy = e.coordinate;
  alert("X: " + xy[0] + ", Y: " + xy[1]);
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kochizufan/pen/bGmxQxO)

But this does not work.

What is wrong? I know not-tiled image can handle with pixel coordinate, according to this example => https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html

But how to handle already-tiled images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those tiles are compatible with a Zoomify source (the tiles at the right and bottom edges are less than 256 pixels wide or high) but OpenLayers does not like the url as it does not contain `TileGroup` or `tileIndex` so you must override the `tileUrlFunction` to prevent OpenLayers adding that.

```
const w = 14132;
const h = 16353;
const url = "https://t.tilemap.jp/maplat/tiles/naramachi_yasui_bunko/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg";

const source = new ol.source.Zoomify({
  size: [w, h],
  url: '',
});

source.setTileUrlFunction((tileCoord) =>
  url
    .replace('{z}', tileCoord[0])
    .replace('{x}', tileCoord[1])
    .replace('{y}', tileCoord[2])
);

const extent = source.getTileGrid().getExtent();

const map = new ol.Map({
  target : 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: source
    })
  ],
  view : new ol.View()
});

map.getView().fit(extent);

map.on('click', (e) => {
  const xy = e.coordinate;
  alert("X: " + xy[0] + ", Y: " + (h + xy[1]));
});
```

The extent will be `[0, -h, w, 0]` but you can add h to the coordinate to see a positive value.

Alternative you can specify `extent: [0, 0, w, h],` in the Zoomify options (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Zoomify-Zoomify.html).

Comment: Thank you Mike!
But if possible, would you please tell me how to change y-axis direction from top to bottom?
Zoomify's y-axis direction is from bottom to top.

Comment: The Openlayers axis cannot be reversed but you could use `alert("X: " + xy[0] + ", Y: " + -xy[1]);`